# Parse list items in python 2.7

Tags: python

I have a values in the list. I want to add these values to dictionary in a particular order. My list values are as follows.

```
ls = [88.0393064668,44.5232914668,30.0179531334,716.37596115,358.691618809,239.463504695,159.076416467,80.0418464668,53.6969898001,645.33885115,323.173063809,215.784468028,290.116906467,145.562091467,97.3771531334,514.29836115,257.652818809,172.104304695,387.169666467,194.088471467,129.728073133,417.24560115,209.126438809,139.753384695,500.253726467,250.630501467,167.4227598,304.16154115,152.584408809,102.058698028,629.296316467,315.151796467,210.436956467,175.11895115,88.0631138086,59.0445013613]
```

These values are in the order of b1, b2, b3, y1, y2, y3, b1, b2, b3, y1, y2, y3 ...

I want these values should be added to the dictionary in the below format
[image]

I have tried itering through list using i%2 method, it did not work well.

Comment: "It did not work well". Does that imply that it did in fact work, but not up to your standards?

Comment: Easiest would be to iterate through the list with `i+=6` instead of `i++`, and set b1,b2,b3,y1,y2,and y3 in each iteration

Comment: Thanks DetectivePikachu for the reply. This method seems to be static. But still I will try for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use python list slice notation [start:stop:step] along with dict comprehension for this

```
>>> keys= ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'y1', 'y2', 'y3']
>>> keys_count = len(keys)
>>> {keys[index]: ls[index:len(ls):keys_count] for index in range(0,keys_count)}

{'b1': [88.0393064668, 159.076416467, 290.116906467, 387.169666467, 500.253726467, 629.296316467], 'b2': [44.5232914668, 80.0418464668, 145.562091467, 194.088471467, 250.630501467, 315.151796467], 'b3': [30.0179531334, 53.6969898001, 97.3771531334, 129.728073133, 167.4227598, 210.436956467], 'y1': [716.37596115, 645.33885115, 514.29836115, 417.24560115, 304.16154115, 175.11895115], 'y3': [239.463504695, 215.784468028, 172.104304695, 139.753384695, 102.058698028, 59.0445013613], 'y2': [358.691618809, 323.173063809, 257.652818809, 209.126438809, 152.584408809, 88.0631138086]}
```